# How to use Metronic on Wordpress(bootstrap theme)

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, plugins

Metronic has a lot of plugings in assets/global/plugins which non of them are Wordpress plugins. How can I use Metronic on a Wordpress installation?

Thank you for your help.

Julia

Answer (score 2):

Simply, you can't. Of course, if you know PHP/Html/jQuery/CSS, then you can re-work it as wordpress plugin.